# Trigger typewriter effect when scrolled in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to figure out a way to trigger a typewriter effects with typed.js once a user scrolls in view to the container holding the text.

What's important in this case is that I'm trying to make this into a reusable element on a wordpress template so every case is self-contained and is not reliant on unique (and limited) identifiers.

I've tried a mix of plugins like inview, waypoints etc some which partly did what I wanted and some not. My current attempt is using waypoints and think I've got the basic setup right however not entirelt sure on how to proceed from here.

My current set up is as follows:

```js
$('.lettering').each(function() {
  
    var animatetext = $(this).html();
    var animateheight = $(this).css('height');
    var animatelettering = $('.lettering').each(function(){
        $(this).typed({ 
      strings: [animatetext],
                typeSpeed: 1,
        });
    });
    new Waypoint.Inview({
      element: this,
      enter: function(direction) {
      },
      entered: function(direction) {
        animatelettering.typed()
      },
      exit: function(direction) {
        animatelettering.typed()
      },
      exited: function(direction) {
      }
    });
  });
```

```css
div {
  height:100vh;
  background-color:red;
}

.highlight {
  color:white;
  background-color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/noframework.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.4/typed.min.js"></script>

<div>

</div>

<div class="highlight">

<span class="lettering">
  row 1 <br>
  row 2 <br>
  row 3
</span>

</div>

<div>

</div>

<div class="highlight">

<span class="lettering">
  row 1 <br>
  row 2 <br>
  row 3
</span>

</div>
```

Would be glad to receive some input on this on how to make this work. Thanks!